# Was bedeutet "schon mal" bei Verneinung?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Was bedeutet "schon mal" in den folgenden Sätzen?

> Parken darf man ***schon mal nicht*** auf den Behindertenparkplätzen.
>   An einen feuerroten Superschurken mit Hörnern und einem Dreizack glaube ich ***schon mal nicht***.

Comment: Nur als Randnotiz: Diese Formulierung ist sehr deutsch und wird z.B. in Österreich selten bis gar nicht verwendet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das "schon mal" deutet an, dass man etwas aufzählen könnte. Man kann sich vielleicht vorstellen, dass man gedanklich eine Liste abarbeitet und diesen Punkt (schon mal) abgehakt hat. Dabei ist übrigens auch egal, ob noch eine Verneinung folgt.

Diese Formulierung legt auch oft nahe, dass der genannte Punkt "selbstverständlich" ist:

> Diese einfache Frage ist schon mal beantwortet. Jetzt versuchen wir, die schwierigen Fragen zu beantworten.

---

*user unknown* hat erwähnt, dass man offen lässt, ob man noch weitere Dinge aufzählen will. Allerdings ist bei so einer einzelnen Aussage nicht unbedingt klar, was dort aufgezählt wird. Man könnte sich verschiedene Möglichkeiten vorstellen:

> Parken darf man schon mal nicht auf den Behindertenparkplätzen. Und Fußball spielen darf man dort auch nicht.

oder

> Parken darf man schon mal nicht auf den Behindertenparkplätzen. Und auf dem Bürgersteig darf man auch nicht parken.

Comment: In all diesen Beispielen ist keine Aufzählung.

Comment: @Robert "....dass man etwas aufzählen **könnte**". Etwa wie in "Parken darf man schon mal nicht auf Behindertenparkplätzen, und auch nicht auf Gehwegen, Straßenbahnschienen oder Zebrastreifen". Ich hatte versucht, die *meaning in context* zu erklären, und die Bedeutung in diesem Fall ist, im Vergleich zu anderen Verwendungen, wie "Ich war *schon mal* in Spanien" oder "Ich gehe *schon mal* nach hause", dass man einen von mehreren Punkten abgehakt hat.

Answer (score 3):

Wie TitanNano schon feststellt, findet sich noch häufiger die Formulierung "schon mal gar nicht".

Klingt zwar nach dem Beginn einer Aufzählung, es schwingt in der Regel noch einiges mehr mit.

Soweit ich sehe, drückt die Floskel aus, dass zunächst mal eine grundlegende Tatsache festgestellt werden soll, die dem Folgenden evtl. eine gewisse Färbung gibt. Zudem wird diese Tatsache nochmal betont, die Aussage intensiviert.

Als englisches Äquivalent würde ich noch "first of all" sehen:

> First of all, I don't believe in the Devil, [and using him to threaten
>   children into obedience is just wrong.]

Die Tatsache, dass der Sprecher nicht an den Teufel glaubt, wird einleitend festgestellt und soll dem Argument insgesamt Gewicht bzw. Emphase verleihen.

Answer (score 2):

Ich persönlich höre und verwende das eigentlich nur als **schon mal *gar* nicht** und es ist mit dem Englischen **especially not** zu vergleichen.

Comment: Die Frage ist aber - bitte nimm das nicht persönlich - schon mal nicht was Du machst oder was ich mache, sondern was in der Sprache Usus ist, was erlaubt ist, was "schon mal nicht" heißt und nicht "schon mal gar nicht". Was soll ein Anfänger mit der Information, was Du persönlich so machst? Ist das was er gehört hat falsch oder Slang?

Answer (score 2):

> Parken darf man schon mal nicht auf den Behindertenparkplätzen.

heißt, der Urheber der Aussage will sich schon mal so weit festlegen, dass Parken auf diesen (für Nichtbehinderte) verboten ist, er will sich aber offen lassen, ob noch mehr verboten ist. Mindestens das Parken ist verboten.

Ähnlich im 2. Fall: Zumindest an einen personalen Teufel glaubt er nicht, womöglich auch nicht an Engel, Dämonen und Götter.